# Central Y align a textfield within a UIScrollView in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextfield

I have a UIScrollView which contains a UILabel with a UITextField directly beneath it.

The scrollview is there to bump up the textField when the keyboard opens for editing

I'm a bit confused to how I vertically center the UITextField in the visible portion of the screen, and to do this across all device sizes.

Is this something I need to do dynamically i.e. calculate the screen height in ViewDidLoad and do exact positioning rather than trying to align centrally vertically?

Or is there a better approach entirely? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some constraints as shown below:

1. Add the UILabel & UITextField to the UIScrollView and position them as needed.
2. Select the UITextField and add a vertical centering constraint to the UIScrollView. To do this, control-click and drag from the UITextField to the UIScrollView and select center vertically in container.
3. Add constraints to the UILabel to position it as desired relative to the UITextField or the top of the UIScrollView.
4. Add constraints to the UIScrollView to pin it's top,bottom,leading, & trailing edges to the superview.

With these constraints, the text field will be vertically centered in the visible area of the screen and will adapt automatically to different screen sizes.

Comment: Ah, I had been just aligning it center to whatever was default, changing it to your suggestion worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear that, Happy coding.